# Cycles in an acyclic complex of projectives are projectives.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module

> Let $P_\bullet$ be a non-negative chain complex in an abelian category $\mathcal A$ such that $H_n(P_\bullet) \cong 0$ and each $P_n$ is projective. Then each $Z_{n} = \partial(P_{n+1})$ is projective.

This is for Proposition 2.5.1.10 at [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net).
It starts using $H_n(P_\bullet) = B_n/Z_n \cong 0$ to get a short exact sequence
$$
0\to Z_n \to P_n\xrightarrow\partial Z_{n-1}\to 0.
$$

In particular $Z_0\cong P_0$ is projective.

Now suppose that $Z_{n-1}$ is projective
Splitting the exact sequence we get
$$
P_n \cong Z_{n}\oplus Z_{n-1}.
$$
We're done if $\mathcal A$ is category of chain complexes of modules for then
$$
P \text{ projective} 
\iff P\oplus Q \text{ free for some } Q
$$

So $Z_n\oplus Z_{n-1}\oplus Q $ is free and $Z_n$ is projective.

However, I don't know how to proceed in general abelian categories.

Comment: In any abelian category, a direct summand of a projective object is again projective. You should try to prove this directly from the definition of "projective object"!

Comment: That's a hell of a tip, thanks!